# Iterator creates a new object or modifies the old one

Tags: java

Just a question for java gurus. If i have a code like follows

```
public void setSeenAttribute(String notificationId , String userId){
        UserNotification userNotification = notificationRepository.getUserNotification(userId);
        if (userNotification != null) {
            for (Notification notification : userNotification.getNotifications()) {
                if (StringUtils.equals(notification.getNotificationId(), notificationId)) {
                    notification.setSeen(true);
                }
            }
            notificationRepository.createUpdateNotification(userNotification);
        }
    }
```

I want to know weather `notification.setSeen(true);` will make a change in the original collection or it's worthless to do something like this ? Or what can be the best practice?

Comment: yes the original collection will be modified as you are updating a reference of Notificaton.

Comment: can i say something like this if i understood correctly "Java does manipulate objects by reference, and all object variables are references. However, Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference; it passes them by value."

Comment: @SaurabhKumar - yes .. you can say that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java - "References to objects are passed by value". So, unless you explicitly reset the reference to point to another object, the current object is modified.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not an Iterator, You are using for each loop to iterate over a collection.
And it is perfectly fine to update values while using for each loop. This is not at all allowed in "Iterator" in Java as they are call Fail-fast.

So,

```
notification.setSeen(true);
```

is updating the Object which is there in collection as new reference ie. notification is pointing to the object which resides in a collection itself.

Comment: It uses an `Iterator` internally. This is called an *enhanced for loop*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like that as the handle is passed as a value but its reference is by object. And to prove it, here's a small example:

```
public class ModifyElementsOfCollection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Wrapper<Integer>> collection = new ArrayList<Wrapper<Integer>>();

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            collection.add(new Wrapper<Integer>(i));
        }

        collection.stream().map(w -> w.element).forEach(System.out::println);

        for(Wrapper<Integer> wrapper : collection) {
            wrapper.element += 1;
        }

        collection.stream().map(w -> w.element).forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    private static class Wrapper<T> {
        private T element;

        private Wrapper(T element) {
            this.element = element;
        }
    }

}
```

Before the second for loop the output are the numbers 0 through 9, afterwards they are 1 through 10. And this works for more complex stuff too.

By the way, this example uses some features from Java 8 to print the results, you could just as well use a for loop of course.